# Run multiple subfolder websites in one separate folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have a main website (example.com). I use CodeIgniter framework there.

I will also use some different subfolders like `example.com/sub1`, `example.com/sub2`. I am using Laravel framework here and those will be completely different from example.com and stored in a different folder. When I started first subdomain, I used `Alias` in Apache2 configuration and it was working perfectly well. However I now need to use a second subfolder. I added a second `Alias` sub2 in Apache configuration that points to the same directory as sub1. Then I changed my .htaccess to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1 !^(img|js|css)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/evim)
    RewriteRule ^ /evim/index.php [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1 !^(img|js|css)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/crm2)
    RewriteRule ^ /crm2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now it works fine. Both example.com/sub1 and example.com/sub2 runs the same application. However in Laravel, it is hard to find which subdomain is running currently. In routes, the application does not see subfolder name. For example if I use `users/login` route, then it matches both `example.com/sub1/users/login` and `example.com/sub2/users/login`. I need to define routes with subfolder name.

I am looking for a solution in htaccess or Laravel to fix the routes.

Comment: In codeigniter I find best way is to create sub directories. called Admin or what ever name you want for back end with its own index.php and application folder. and another folder called catalog the main index.php would use the catalog as application folder. If you would like to make libraries for both directory put it in the systems lib folder.  It works I am making similar one all most done just working on admin security Also I find less mucking around with the htacess the better.

Comment: example.com uses CodeIgniter, however the subfolder application uses Laravel. I want to keep them completely separate in file system.

Comment: I would just try and stick to one frame work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Request::server('HTTP_HOST')` to get which site is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this pattern (as sub domains) and it may perhaps avoid problems.

```
http://site1.foo.com http://site2.foo.com
```

In CodeIgniter Route.php you can do the following:

```
$server_link = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);

if ( $server_link[0] == "site1" )
{
   $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
   // Some Other Routes
}
```

I think you can do the same thing for Laravel routes.

Comment: Yep, subdomains would be a very simple solution, however i cannot use subdomains.